# What condition ensures that the power series $\sum_{n \geq 1} a_n x^n$ also converges rational number?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose the series $ \sum_{n \geq 1}a_n$ converges in the field $ \mathbb{Q}$ of rationals i.e., $ \sum_{n \geq 1} a_n \in \mathbb{Q}$.

What condition ensures that the power series $\sum_{n \geq 1} a_n x^n$ also converges in the field rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Here take $a_n \in \mathbb{Q}$ to be arbitrary but impose condition on the argument $x$ .

Any help please.

For $x=1$, the answer is ok.

What are the other arguments $x$?

Comment: Your first sentence makes no sense.

Comment: @zhw., Why sir?   I want to mean that the series $ \sum a_n$ converges in rational  field $\mathbb{Q}$ i.e., the series sums to a rational number.

Comment: That series has no $r$ in it!

Comment: @zhw. I think the OP simply meant that $\sum_{n\geq 1} a_n \in \mathbb{Q}$, and called the value of the sum $r$.

Comment: @ClementC., yes you are right. I meant $ \sum a_n \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: What makes you think that for $x=-1$ the answer is "ok" ?

Comment: Do you also require that the $a_n$ be rational ?

Comment: Integer ? How could that converge ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, sorry my mistake. Considering $a_n \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\sum_n\frac1{2^n}$$ converges to $1$ and

$$\sum_n\frac{x^n}{2^n}$$ converges to

$$s(x):=\frac x{2-x}$$ for $|x|<2$.

Then

$$s(x)=q\in\mathbb Q$$ when $$x=s^{-1}(q), q\in\mathbb Q.$$

The answer will be similar for other entire series. (Here, coincidentally, $x$ is also rational.)

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer. Can we do the answer for arbitrary rational number $a_n \in \mathbb{Q}$ and rather characterising the variables $x$? Any hints. Because you chose $a_n$ to be particular .

Comment: @@Yves Daoust, Can you give some hintz for arbitrary $a_n \in \mathbb{Q}$ and charaterising the variables $x$? I mean keep $a_n$ to be arbitrary rational number and determine the condition on the variables $x$ for which the power result holds.

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR: the principle generalizes to any entire function, leading to transcendental functions of arbitrary complexity. I am not sure that we have a general theory of when they take rational values.

Comment: You didn't answer about "the answer is ok for $x=-1$".

Comment: I have deleted $x=-1$, as you see my question